# How does Jmeter show the website resource in label column at summary report

Tags: javascript, html, http, jmeter

[image]

I run the HTTP request for test.

Is there any settings to show the website resource loaded in the report?

Like Label at below

```
/css/MyCss.css
/js/MyJS.js
/images/MyImage.jpg
```

......and other resources request to the Server test,not the 「Total」 one result.

Or what should I do to reach the needs I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable styles, scripts and images loading you need to tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` box, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

By default requests would be named as `HTTP Request-0`, `HTTP Request-1`, etc because these requests are being executed in parallel and in the same transaction as the main HTTP Request which retrieves the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) . however the URL will still be visible in i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and .jtl results file

[image]

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) article for more details.

If you want to see the URLs in the listeners instead you can tick `Functional Testing Mode` box in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

[image]

or add `subresults.disable_renaming=true` line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation). JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,sorry for too late to response.I make the 「Retrieve all Embeded Resources」settings,and it can work and see the request body on the view source tree.

Comment: But it still one result 「Http request」the one label shows on the summary report.
Is the Jmeter doing originaly? If I want to see the url label every count.